What is (was) this fish carcass found on an eastern Long Island beach?
An acquaintance sent me these photos of fish remains that they found on a beach on the east end of Long Island, NY. The site lies near Gardiners Bay near a channel that is used by trawlers travelling to and from port.
This portion from behind the fish's head is very large compared to what we would normally see. The only real scale I can provide is the fourth photo, a vid capture showing an 11 year old waving their croc above the remains.
I am an avid surf fishing angler with considerable experience in natural history. I am confident it isn't one of the usual suspects such as Striped Bass, Bluefish, or any of the typical bottom fish. I am also confident that it isn't the Montauk Monster.
In the summer we do get some random visitors from further south. Tarpon and Black Drum are occasionally caught in nets near here. There are also cast-offs from the trawlers that go who-knows-where.
So, what is this fish?


Could it be one of the sturgeon or related species (gar etc.) no idea what's in the region personally, but the scales don't look like conventional fish scales to me.

The first picture made me double-take, though I was seeing a bird's wing. The scale-type is known as "ctenoid" (i.e. jagged, comb-like or irregular), which narrows it down a bit to a perciform (perch-like) fish, or something rarer with the same - certainly ray-finned. Beyond that, I've no idea.

@JiminyCricket. Black Drum would fit both conditions. And they get large enough.

@bob1 while Atlantic sturgeon carcasses occasionally show up on the beaches here, this isn't like them from what I can tell.
